# What type of word is "maybe" that allows it to be placed at the start of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Maybe I will.

Is allowed.

> Probably I will.

Is not-so allowed.

All I know is that they are both adverbs.

What is special about the word "maybe" that allows English speakers to use it in different ways to how we use "possibly" and "probably"?

Why is:

> It's probably the best I've heard

so much more likely to be said (and why does it sound more correct) than:

> It's maybe the best I've heard

Comment: Maybe (it may be) that *maybe* carries some flavor of its source in the two separate words. In your last example, *It's maybe*, could be replaced by *It may be*, giving an expression common at the beginning of a sentence. (I don't agree that *Probably I will.* is impossible, though it's less likely than *I probably will.*)

Comment: What's wrong with starting a sentence with *probably*?

Comment: @nnnnnn probably it's uncommon so it sounds weird (incorrect/like a second language speaker) to me

Comment: Adverb distribution is flexible but notoriously idiosyncratic. 'Maybe' being not as formal as 'perhaps' and certainly 'possibly', one might expect a rather freer distribution.

Comment: “*Perhaps* I will”: no one objects. “Lord willing, I will,” “Fortunately, I will”: People might insist on the comma, but I think everyone is happier with the adverb(ials) either at the front or the back, not between “I” and “will.” “I probably will”: although, as noted, you *could* put the adverb at the front or back (especially set off with a comma), it’s happiest in the middle. I don’t think there’s any commonality that we can point to among the words that are typically given one position or other.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives maybe as a adverb, noun and adjective. It is most likely to occur at the beginning of a sentence as an adverb.

The etymology is given as

> **Etymology**: Shortened < it may be < it pron. + may v.1 + be v. and can also occur with a subordinate clause, and as a noun.

Maybe was uncommon in English before the mid-19th century when it was considered poetic or dialect. Its origins can be seen in the hyphenated form.

1825   J. Jennings "Observations on the Dialects of West England". *May-be, mâ-be, perhaps; for which one of these words is almost invariably used.*

1829   J. Hunter "Hallamshire Glossary". *May-be. This is at least as good as the hybrid word perhaps, by which it has been supplanted.*

As an adverb at the beginning of a sentence - "Maybe I will visit her tomorrow" - it is almost always a free modifier, i.e. it modifies the whole of [what appears to be] the main clause.

As far as

> Probably I will. Is not-so allowed.

is concerned. I cannot put it better than Jack O'Flaherty above:

> (I don't agree that Probably I will. is impossible, though it's less likely than I probably will.)

Answer (score 1):

From [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence%20adverb)

> **sentence adverb** (grammar)
> an adverb that limits or describes the meaning of an entire statement rather than just a single word or phrase
> *"Similarly" and "hopefully" often function as sentence adverbs.*

I think it's often useful to refer to the usage as ***whole** sentence adverb* to emphasize that aspect. Because the adverb applies to the *entire* containing sentence, it's often just a stylistic choice whether to put it *before* or *after* the utterance it modifies. It could also occur *within* the utterance, but that would often leave more scope for alternative syntactic breakdown / terminology.

---

I just searched Google Books for the sequence ["**functions as a sentence adverb**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22functions%20as%20a%20sentence%20adverb%22) to find some more "typical" examples. Specific examples from that search include ***sadly, clearly, happily, importantly,*** but obviously OP's ***maybe, probably, possibly*** are all of the same ilk in this respect.

---

EDIT: I see no real significance to the fact that we're more likely to say...

> ***Maybe** that's a good idea / That's **probably** a good idea*
> rather than
> ***Probably** that's a good idea / That's **maybe** a good idea*.

...where all four versions do occur, are perfectly valid, and mean the same. It's just that once a given construction has *started* to become "favoured" (perhaps by mere chance), it tends to become increasingly "idiomatically established".

Comment: Since maybe, probably, and possibly are all sentence adverbs this can't be the correct term to separate maybe from the other two?

Comment: The dividing line between a "standard, verb-specific" adverb and a "sentence adverb" isn't always clear-cut. Note that it's meaningless to attempt to differentiate ***maybe*** from ***possibly / probably*** on the grounds of whether they're "verb-specific" or "sentence-wide", because ***each individual usage must be analysed in context*** (a "part of speech" normally *only* applies to a term ***as used in a specific context***, not to the term itself in isolation).

Comment: Well, nobody would **say** "Probably", with all syllables and whistles, at the beginning of a sentence. The normal way to pronounce that is "Probly", with less hubbub.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Prolly not! But I have to admit it's only when I really stop to think about it that I realise I rarely enunciate even that /b/ in the *spoken* version of what I just wrote there. Until a few minutes ago I thought my use of ***prolly*** there was primarily just an affectation intended to save me a couple of keystrokes in SMS text messages. My "inner voice" would have assured me I was making at least *some* effort to pronounce the word as it's written, but now I have to admit that actually I usually don't bother to articulate any more than "just enough to be understood"!

Comment: ... and neither does anybody else. Once you realize that, a lot of details about how and why language changes become clearer.